# How to move (up/down) code lines in Android Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, android-studio

In eclipse we use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to move a line up or down.

Is there any shortcut in Android Studio to do the same?
Or any quick way to avoid copy & paste?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To move a line:

Place the caret at the line to be moved.

Do one of the following:

On the main menu, choose `Code | Move Line Up or Code | Move Line Down`.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36712915/3715151) works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 12):

If you want the exact behavior of eclipse you can do this:

File --> Settings --> Keymap --> Code--> Folding--> assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to "**Move Line Up/down**" instead of "**Move Statement up/down**"

Answer (score 8):

There are (at least) two kinds of *Moving line up/down* in Android Studio: The "intelligent" one and the "dumb" one. Like IngoAlbers said, the dumb one (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><Arrow></kbd>) just moves the line.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><Arrow></kbd> instead, makes the functionality more intelligent:

- It doesn't leave the current "context":

  ```
  public static void test() {
      int i = 5;
      Runnable theodor = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("Hi!");
          }
      };
  }
  ```

  Moving the `int i = 5;`line down one step, brings you this:

  ```
  public static void test() {
      Runnable theodor = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("Hi!");
          }
      };
      int i = 5;
  }
  ```
- It keeps methods together:

  ```
  public static void hello() {
      System.out.println("Hello!");
  }

  public static void dinner() {
      System.out.println("Dinner's ready!");
  }

  public static void sleep() {
      System.out.println("Good night.");
  }
  ```

  Moving the line `public static void sleep() {` up one step moves the complete `sleep()` method above `dinner()`:

  ```
  public static void hello() {
      System.out.println("Hello!");
  }

  public static void sleep() {
      System.out.println("Good night.");
  }

  public static void dinner() {
      System.out.println("Dinner's ready!");
  }
  ```
- In most cases, it is just annoying. ;-)

Comment: For those on Mac, Shift+Command+Up/Down is the "smart one" and Shift+Options+Up/Down is the "dumb one" (though I personally think each got their use cases, but yeah you're  more than likely to want to use the "smart" type of line moving in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio move code lines**

MacOS

```
Code -> Move Line Up/Down
```

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In windows, you can go to 'Keymap' settings(File --> Settings --> Keymap --> Editor Actions) to customize this action and more actions.

I think it's a better way.