# Shortcut for moving code block up and down in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

is there any shortcut for move a selected code block up and down in android studio?

In Visual Studio 2010+ I just select my block, hold ALT-Key and press arrow up / arrow down. Then, the selected block float up/down.

Is there a similar action in Android Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to move (up/down) code lines in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735732/how-to-move-up-down-code-lines-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try Ctrl-Shift-Up or down arrow. I know intellij and as this is based on intellij that might work.

Comment: What if i want to move selected code, in a line, to left or right

Answer (score 2):

On Mac:

`Command` + `Shift` + `Up/down arrows`

Comment: notice it have this by default - this is the most stupidest hotkey they could have chosen for mac. cmd+shift up down is a native hotkey for selecting all text from the cursor and down/up (don't have home/end/page up/page down on the keyboard) - changing this hotkey right now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Up/Down Arrows` to move the selected block up or down.

[Here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) is a list of shortcut keys for `Windows&Linux`.

Answer (score 1):

I try on Mac `Cmd` + `Shift` + `Up/Down`, work fine and not conflict with others MacOs shortcut

on Window user `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Up/Down`

You can modify it on reference / type shortcut in search